# Can a web server store files at a host?

Tags: webserver, nodemcu

I'm trying to create a web server for my NodeMCU project, but I would also want it to write a JSON/TEXT file and store it at a host computer accessing the web page. Is it possible to write a JSON using HTTP requests?

Thank you!

Comment: Anything else that's needed here? Case closed?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

You would use the [HTTP `post` method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods) to send a JSON structure to a remote host. Hence, in the NodeMCU firmware you can use the [`post()` function of the `http` module](https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/http/#httppost) like so:

```
http.post('http://httpbin.org/post',
  'Content-Type: application/json\r\n',
  '{"hello":"world"}',
  function(code, data)
    if (code < 0) then
      print("HTTP request failed")
    else
      print(code, data)
    end
  end)
```